# Efficiently prepend a row to an existing Excel file

Tags: java, excel, scala, apache-poi

We are generating a large Excel file using Apache POI's `SXSSFWorkbook` in our Scala application.

The problem is: we only know the universal set of columns once we reach the end of our stream, since each row we stream into memory can potentially introduce new columns that need outputting to the Excel file.

Our approach so far has been: stream each row into memory, write to the Excel file via `SXSSFWorkbook`, and at the end of the process, calculate the "header row" and prepend it into the Excel file.

However, we cannot determine how to prepend a row to an Excel file without loading the whole Excel file into memory.

Has anyone else had any experience with this?

Comment: Are you able to create an array of your headers?  This would have your main data in array1 and your header data in array2, where you can put them where needed.

Comment: The data is coming from a large database table, so this would require 2 traversals of the table: first traversal to calculate the universal set of columns for the Excel file, and a second traversal to write the body rows to the Excel file. We can do this, but if we can find a way to prepend a row to an Excel file, then we only need to traverse the DB once.

Comment: For a streaming writing approach like `SXSSF` you will need the first data to be streamed first. There is no way around. Also you cannot prepend a row to a sheet without shifting all already existing rows one row down. And even if you would let the first row empty at first to be filled later, this cannot be done in a streaming manner using `apache poi` `SXSSF`. So, no, no way using `apache poi`. Best of all bad solutions will be double traversing the database to have the first needed row before starting `SXSSF`.

Comment: Stream into a high-efficiency in-memory representation, then when you have everything, write out via Apache POI?